# Add person to person field sharepoint

Tags: powershell

Currently I have this script as test:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Web”) | Out-Null

$User = 'usernamehere'
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'passwordhere' -AsPlainText -Force
$SPOUrl = "sharepointlisthere"
$SPOList = "Add2AD"

$SPListItemColumns = @{
        FirstName = "Title"
        LastName = "Achternaam"
        Title = "Functie"
        Managerf = "Teamleider"
        Status = "Status"
        Mail = "Mail"
        Laptop = "Laptop"
        Accountnaam = "Accountnaam"
}

#Connect to SharePoint Online
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOUrl)
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, $Pass)
#Get the list
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($SPOList)
$Query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(100) 
$Items = $List.GetItems($Query)
$Context.Load($Items)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($item in $Items) 
{
    #Get list item for later reference
    $ListItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem]$listItem = $List.GetItemById($Item.FieldValues["ID"])
    if ($item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.Status] -eq "Nee") {
        Write-Verbose "Processing list item $Firstname $LastName with ID=$($item.FieldValues["ID"])"
        #Put the fieldvalues in variables.
        $Managerf = $item.FieldValues[$SPListItemColumns.Managerf]
        $Managerf = $Managerf.LookupValue
        Write-Output $Managerf

        $ListItem[$SPListItemColumns.Accountnaam] = "sgouman@test.nl"
        $ListItem.Update()
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        }
}
```

But whenever I run this script I get this error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "There are invalid data used to update this listitem or the field is readonly."

so what could it be? I already tried with the user as email address and user as just the normal name none of these work. I want to update the name that is in office 365 so we can later use that field to email them.

Comment: OK, I found it worked if I replaced the email address with JUST the user's ID number, not in quotes. In my case the user ID was 12, but I'm not entirely sure how to integrate that into your script. However, there are a few methods listed to get that bit of data [over here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/14a7a6ed-e0cd-439d-89e4-2fd9a785e131/how-can-i-get-the-id-number-of-a-sharepoint-online-user).